# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class -NULL value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Rails app is generating this error whenever validation aren't met:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

**post_controller.rb**:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @show_post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @new_post = Post.new
  end



  def create
     @create_post = Post.new(params[:post])

     if @create_post.save
       redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post was save"
       else
     render "new"
     end
  end




  def edit
    @edit_post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
    @update_post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @update_post.update_attributes(params[:post])
      redirect_to posts_path , :notice => "YOUR POST has been update"
    else
       render "edit"

    end

  end

  def destroy
    @destroy_post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @destroy_post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "You succressfuly delete #{@destroy_post}"

  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**:

```
<h1>My blog</h1>

<% @posts.each do |post|%>
    <h2><%= link_to post.title, post%></h2>
    <p><%= post.content%></p>
    <p>
        <%= link_to "EDIT", edit_post_path(post)%>
        <%= link_to "Delete", post ,:confirm => "Are you sure?" , :method => :delete%>
    </p>
    <hr>
<% end%>

<p>
    <%= link_to "Add new post", new_post_path %>


</p>
```

**post.rb**:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :content

   validates :title, :content, :presence => true
   validates :title, :length => { :minimum => 2}
   validates :title, :uniqueness =>true

end
```

The error is raised in the following context:

```
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>Add new post</h1>
2: <%= form_for @new_post do |form|%>
3:  <p>
4:      <%= form.label :title%><br />
5:      <%= form.text_field :title%>
```

I don't think I have a problem with my code? Or the value is just `nil` and that's why it comes with this error?

Comment: Where exactly is this error being raised?

Comment: @Axsuul -NoMethodError in Posts#create
Nobita - what do you mean? sorry new in Ror

Comment: I suggest building an app using Rails scaffolding, and learning from what that generates. Don't worry, it'll take you all of 5 minutes to do and you'll have learned a lot of Rails syntax by the end.

Comment: @Led: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop doing this: `@create_post`, `@new_post`, `@show_post`, `@edit_post` etc, etc...

Start doing this: `@post`.

The problem is that your object is called `@create_post` in your `create` action. If the model is invalid, your create action is calling `render "new"`. The "new" view expects `@new_post` to be set, which it isn't. `@new_post` is `nil`, and `form_for(nil)` is raising an error. You should just be calling the variable `@post` in every method, there is *no gain* for naming them `@create_post` or `@new_post`. It adds meaningless clutter and, in this case, breaks things.

Comment: thanks i thought @<action>_<controllerName> would help me specifying in what action im working with thanks alot though :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess: your form is in a partial (the file the contains the form code begins for `_`), so when you call it from the `create` action the variable `@new_post` is not instantiated, and you get the error. That's why the code generated by `rails scaffold` works: the scaffold code names the variable `@post` in the `new`, `create`, `edit` and `update` actions, so they can use the variable `@post` in the partial `_form`, which they share.

Anway, when you make questions like this, it's better if you give people more informations (the version of Rails used and two or three lines of the error, for example).